# recorrer arreglo he insertarlo datos extraidos en base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

tengo unas varible que son un arrays con diferentes tipos de modelos de carros y nececito leerlo ya sea con un `for` o algo similar para luego esos datos obtenidos insertarlos en una base de datos en sus respestivas marcas

los arrays son los siguientes ..

```
/////////////// este array ira enla tabla toyota ///////////////////
        var toyotaCars= [
            {
                text: "4runner",
                value:"4runner",
                disabled:true,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                text: "camry",
                value:"camry",
                selected: false
            },
            {
                text: "corolla",
                value:"corolla",
                selected: false

            }
           ];


/////////////// este array ira enla tabla honda ///////////////////
        var hondaCars= [
            {
                text: "accord",
                value:"accord",
                disabled:true,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                text: "civic",
                value:"civic",
                selected: false
            },
            {
                text: "crv",
                value:"crv",
                selected: false

            }
           ];

/////////////// este array ira enla tabla nissan ///////////////////

     var nissanCars= [
            {
                text: "murano",
                value:"murano",
                disabled:true,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                text: "skylan",
                value:"skylan",
                selected: false
            },
            {
                text: "350-Z",
                value:"350-Z",
                selected: false

            }
           ];
```

la tabla para insertar los datos extraidos quiero que quede asi

```
--------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
 id     | honda        | toyota       | nissan       | 
--------|--------------|--------------|--------------|  
  1     | accord       | 4runner      | murano       |
--------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
  2     | civic        | camry        | skylan       |
--------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
  3     | crv          | corolla      | 350-z        |
--------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
```

como veran los arrays estan llamados por sus respectivas marcas ejemplo el array **toyotaCars** sus valores irian insertado en el campo **toyota**,el de  **hondaCars** en el campo **honda** etc... alguien me podria dar una idea de como puedo hacer esta funcion que me inserte los modelos de vehiculos en sus respectivos campos?

lo que pasa es que estaba usando una libreria  para unos inputs selects y requeria estos array para hacer los `options` y pues imaginen cambie de libreria y la que estoy usando ahora usa las etiquetas html normal osea la estructura `selects` y `options` y quiero que los modelos de vehiculos que tenia en esos array ahora esten en la base de datos, solo estoy haciendo el ejemplo con 3 modelos de autos y 3 marcas de vehiculos pero el codigo real tiene mas **50** marcas de vehiculos y mas de **1000** modelos de autos  por lo que hacer esto uno por uno en la base de datos no seria muy gracioso pero ya los tengo en los arrays de el ejemplo solo me faltaria insertarlos en la base de datos.

ojala y me puedan ayudar

Comment: No crees que sería mejor almacenar la información en tablas diferentes?. Una para cada marca, sería más sencillo.

Comment: Los comentarios en tu código hacen pensar que proyectas usar una tabla por cada marca, lo cual sería un error. Esto se resolvería fácilmente con un modelo relacional donde la marca sería identificada por un id, e incluso los modelos también deberían ir en una tabla aparte. Hablamos entonces de tres tablas al menos: `marca, modelo, marca_modelo`

Comment: exacto me disculpo ! pero si es asi serian 3 tablas como dice @A.Cedano

Comment: Si crees que es necesario modifica tu pregunta

Comment: La cuestión es que si te decides por organizar mejor las tablas, implementado como ya se ha dicho, un modelo relacional, sería interesante que pudieras **producir un solo array**, no un array por cada marca. En ese único array, incluyes para cada elemento la clave `marca` y a partir de ahí sería más fácil de trabajar para hacer las inserciones respectivas en cada tabla. Debes decir si esto es posible o no. El hecho es que ahora mismo tú creas arrays *a mano* por cada marca y creo que no es necesario, es más, lo que hace es complicar las cosas.